# How to dynamically embed Python code snippets to source file in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

For example, I have a source file like this:

```py
from math import *

# dynamically import `calculate` function 
# from other files here
calculate = my_dynamic_import("xxx.py")

print(calculate(1))
```

And two code snippet which is readonly:

```py
# file my_sqrt.py
def calculate(num):
    return sqrt(num)
```

```py
# file my_sin.py
def calculate(num):
    return sin(num)
```

How can I implement `my_dynamic_import` function to enable the functionality to load and switch the `calculation` function from different code snippets dynamically and programatically?

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic import for this? You can just import both and select whichever you want. Since `import`is a regular statement, you could also *conditionally* do a regular import.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The code snippet could be provided by customers, and it can't be imported before we finally get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import functions from another python file based on a string, the you could use something like `exec(open('xxx.py').read())`. Make sure that this file is safe though because this executes all code inside the file, which could be malicious if left unchecked.

Comment: this is exactly what i need.